# :rocks scene invalid and crashing. what's wrong with the batch code?

Tags: batch-file, rocks

Basically, I've been working on a game that allows you to create a world. It's extremely new and I've been working on it for about 30 minutes. The third-party external programs are cmdmenusel and CHOICE. At the rocks scene, ( :rocks ), when I click Expand, it crashes with a quick message. Can you please help me see what's wrong with my code?

```
@echo off
title Develop a World
cd z
:: Not a fully developed program. 
:: Do not distribute.
:: (C) Copyright Bextem 2016  - Present
:love
cls
color D
echo There is nothing but love.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Grow"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto hope
goto love
:hope
cls
color E
echo There is love and hope.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Grow"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto start
goto hope
:start
cls
color F
echo With love and hope, there is a start.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Grow"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto rocks
goto start
:rocks
cls
color 8
echo There are rocks in your land.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Grow"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto mountain
goto rocks
:mountains
cls
color 8 
echo There is a mountain.
echo.
type mountain.txt
echo.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Expand"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto manymts
goto mountains
:manymts
cls
color 8
echo There are caves and mountains.
echo.
type mt.txt
cmdMenuSel f870 "Crumble" "Grow"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto earth
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto stone
goto manymts
:stone
echo There is nothing but stone.
echo Press any key to undo your mistake.
pause >nul
goto manymts
:earth
cls
color 6
echo There is dirt and mountains.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Water" "Shine"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto earthwater
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto earthshine
goto earth
:earthwater
cls
color 61
echo There is moist soil and mountains.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Shine" "Water"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto earthwatershine
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto floodearth1
goto earthwater
:earthshine
cls
color 16
echo There is hot soil and mountains.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Water" "Shine"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto earthwatershine
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto droughtearth1
goto earthshine
:floodearth1
cls
color 2
echo Your world has flooded.
echo Press any key to undo your mistake.
pause >nul
goto earthwater
:droughtearth2
cls
color 6
echo The world burns from the sun.
echo Press any key to undo your mistake.
pause >nul
goto earthshine
:earthwatershine
cls
color A2
echo The soil is floroushing.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Grow" "Plant"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto dirtpile
goto earthwatershine
:dirtpile
cls
color 6
echo There is a pile of dirt and mountains
echo +1 more.
cmdMenuSel f870 "Grow Dirt" "Grow Mountains" "Inventory"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto dirtpilehuge
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto stone
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 3 goto Inventory
goto dirtpile
:Inventory
echo PLAYER'S INVENTORY (PAGE 1)
echo You have: 
echo Loves: %love%
echo Hopes: %hope%
echo Starts: %start%
echo Rocks: %rocks%
echo Mountains: %mountains%
echo Caves: %caves%
echo Soil: %soil%
:startgame
set love=0
set hope=0
set start=0
set rocks=0
set mountain=0
set caves=0
set soil=0
set humans=0
goto love
```

Comment: Please regard the following help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: Hint for debugging a batch file: Remove `@echo off` from batch file and save it. Open a command prompt window which results in starting `cmd.exe` with option `/K`  to __keep open__ the window after execution of 1 or more batch files, type the name of your batch file with full path enclosed in double quotes, and press RETURN to execute it. You see now the command lines executed after preprocessing. And you see also error messages like label not found causing exit of batch interpreting. Double clicking a batch file results in running it with `cmd.exe` with option `/C` for __close__ on finish.

Answer (score 0):

You have `goto mountain` instead of `goto mountains` in the `:rocks` section.

Look just two lines beneath that goto to see your typo. There is no `:mountain` anywhere in your code. Only `:mountains`.

Hence, just change:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto mountain
```

.. to:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto mountains
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed this before.